# supabase retrieve access token on server side

Tags: sveltekit, supabase

anyone know how to retrieve the access token when you click "send password recovery"?
the redirect_url looks something like this: `http://localhost:5173/#access_token=eyJhbG...&token_type=bearer&type=recovery` and its impossible to access the arguments on the server side due to the `#`.
any ideas?
I'm using sveltekit.

Comment: For server-side you need to use the PKCE flow. See the docs here: https://supabase.com/docs/guides/auth/server-side/email-based-auth-with-pkce-flow-for-ssr?framework=sveltekit